# Refreshing a table's content in IOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an app that displays premium content in a tableview inside an `UIViewController` . When it loads it checks in the `viewDidLoad` method wether the subscription is active or not and displays the content accordingly .
My problem is that I can't manage to refresh the content right after the user confirms buying the subscription . I overpopulated my `ViewController.m` file with `[self checkSubscription]` and the only way to refresh is by navigating to another tab and then back(added the `[self checkSubscription]` in `viewWillAppear` method)  , or by tapping the buy button or the restore button and it instantly refreshes .

```
-(void)checkSubscription{

NSLog(@"Checking");
if ([[JCSubscriptionManager sharedManager] isSubscriptionActive]) {

    _buyBtn.enabled = NO;
    _restoreBtn.enabled = NO;
    _restoreBtn.hidden = YES;
    _buyBtn.hidden = YES;
    _msgLabel.hidden = YES;

} else {

    _buyBtn.enabled = YES;
    _restoreBtn.enabled = YES;

    _restoreBtn.hidden = NO;
    _buyBtn.hidden = NO;
    _msgLabel.hidden = NO;


}
[self retrieveData];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

}

Any ideas/suggestions?

I am using JC auto renewal manager for IAP . I have found the exact line of code where I get the confirmation(NSLog) that the subscription is now active and changes the value of the subscription variable. After that I have added these lines :

```
DTPremiumViewController *vc = [[DTPremiumViewController alloc]init];
    [vc.tableView reloadData];
    [vc viewWillAppear:NO];
```

And still no luck.

Comment: Did you try to `reloadData` after the response comes from the server

Comment: Is `retreiveData` async? Or does it update the array that populates the tableView?

Comment: What happens when _"user confirms buying the subscription"_? Any delegate/other method gets called? Add that code.

Comment: is your issue unable to get status of subscription while populating/ displaying info in tableview?

Comment: @joshi yes i did . Or I think so ( I just started using obj C)

Comment: @CharanGiri I have no problem populating the table . Only problem is that it does not refresh automatically after the purchase is complete . The user has to navigate away and then back to refresh

Comment: Is your issue knowing when to call `checkSubscription`?

Comment: @DaanOlislagers I don't know exactly what async means . Sorry I am a beginner . retrieveData is a method that connects to the server , gets data and populates the array , conditioned of course by wether the subscription is active or not .

Comment: @Larme Yes . Something like that . I have tried to call it almost everywhere . I even tried to put a timer to it to pass the response from the server

Comment: With `DTPremiumViewController *vc = [[DTPremiumViewController alloc]init];[vc.tableView reloadData];[vc viewWillAppear:NO];`, your create a new instance of your VC. A way to do it, could be using a delegate method of your `JCSubscriptionManager`.

Comment: Well, then it means it is async (async stands for asynchronous). You should call the reloadData when the server returns the data and the array is repopulated. You will probably have a listener or notification somewhere.